# Considering going back to former employer

Tags: employer

I recently left a job and now I am hearing from current employees that they are going to need some help. I know that they would definitely need me and I am considering going back part time for extra money, it would be for approximately 3 weeks. Two things though, first no one has asked me but I am considering asking them if this is possible, secondly I wonder how this would pan out from an HR perspective? Is this a possibility?

Comment: This varies from company to company, and even within a company can vary from month to month or year to year. There is no way we can know unless you tell us who the employer is and we call them for you. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm confused what you are asking. No one from your old company has contacted you, but you want to ask them if they need part-time help? What do you mean, will it "pan out from an HR perspective?" And we can't tell you whether your old company will take you back or if your current company will allow side work. That is completely dependent on the company.

Comment: You might consider editing your question to clarify what, specifically, you are asking. We cannot guess what policies might be in place at the companies you are involved with, so you should find those out (by asking them). You might also consider phrasing your question as looking for things you should consider before deciding what to do. (Disclosure: I have already provided an answer to this question assuming this was the intent of your question.)

Comment: Why did you leave the company to start with?

Answer (score 6):

**Returning to a place where you used to work will not be the same.** Even if you just go there to have lunch with friends who are still there, it is different. Going back there to work will be different. You will not have the same status as you had when you worked there. You need to be prepared for that.

**You also need to make sure any current employment contract(s) you have** (i.e., your current job) **do not prevent you from working other jobs while you are employed with them**. Many companies don't have a problem with their people working on independent projects in their free time, but may have a problem with employment at another company doing related work with similar duties as you currently have with them.

Finally, **you will have to decide which employer wins if there is a conflict**. If your full-time job requires some overtime that prevents you from meeting your commitment to your part-time job, you'll need to know how you're going to handle that.

But the biggest thing is that returning to a former workplace is different, and often weird, and it may just be better for everyone if you stay away. It's good that you want to help, but be sure you're not feeling motivated by a need to be a hero and come back to save the day, just like old times.

Comment: I returned to a former employer after 2 months, here's how it went: Co-workers - "Oh, you're back?",  Me - "Yup",  Co-workers - "Cool",  Me - "Cool".  I guess my point is that returning may or may not be weird depending.

Comment: @Hobbes, Yes, I returned to a former company after 6 months working somewhere else, and I had a similar experience as yours. I think the difference between our experience and what OP is asking is that you and I came back and committed to the company again. OP appears to be hoping to hang on to the best of both worlds. It may work out. It may not.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your relationship with previous employer and depends on a company policy.
If they really need you (and can afford you and so on) and you want to come back, everybody is happy. In my experience if your relation with previous workplace was good enough there's no problem for coming back. There's even possibility you won't have to come though all interviewing process and only have to negotiate contract.
So yes, there's a possibility that you'll be accepted back on better conditions. Especially that you have people on the inside who will support you.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your current employer and your old company culture.

In our company many people left the company over the last years. Some of them returned, as our company normally welcomes former employees.

For those who returned, it wasn't the same. Many of them needed to get a new "clique". As many of their old friends and colleges doesn't like their disappearance and find others to hang around with.

Many of the "returners" go away after a few months or after a year, as they find another good or even better job.

For the company itself, it was really helpful to get them back, as they've had a few new perspectives on some topics. This was really helpful to get some new input.

But some of them, who came back, just wanted to do the same as before. This behavior wasn't really welcome for all the other employees, which just see the point, that those returners just failed in their new job and want to do the stuff they already know.

If you want to stay at your current company and just want to work for a few hours a week in your old company, it may be ok for you. If you want to leave your new job and go back to your old company, it may be fine for you, but be prepared that this may be a little bit harder, than before. Even if you do the same things as before.